# How to make AWSSDK for .NET Core use a non-default credentials profile in a console application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I have a .NET Core 3.1 **console** application that I'm using to access Secrets Manager during development (so, from my local machine).

By default, when the console app runs, the AWSSDK uses credentials from the [default] profile in my /Users/me/.aws/credentials file.

I want to use appsettings.json to make the AWSSDK use the "sandbox" profile from my credentials file, instead of the "default" profile.

My credentials file has the default and sandbox profiles (values shown are not real):

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XCR54W7SGBKKGQGUE95W
aws_secret_access_key = 9kGUHfDjqNFiv8SPjumGqyrDOZ3677qt5&Nn4A/u
[sandbox]
aws_access_key_id = QT29NYY3K2D9DU2YU4M9
aws_secret_access_key = 56yS98IIxX0kxH/W70K61I7QqmsJmjDdSVEx83Gr
```

In appsettings.json, I have created an AWS section:

```
    "AWS": {
        "Profile": "sandbox",
        "AWSProfileName": "sandbox"
    }
```

*Note: I specified keys `Profile` and `AWSProfileName` because I have seen mixed information regarding what it should actually be named, so I'm covering all bases.*

Next, Program.cs/Main.  From this article [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration), I need to create an instance of HostBuilder, which will load the configuration from appsettings.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("AwsSdk");

    using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
    
    // Application code should start here.
    var result = SecretsManager.GetSecret();
    
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

In the end, this does not work.  I still receive an exception:

```
(User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXXXX is not authorized to perform:
 secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: XXXXXXXX with an explicit deny in 
an identity-based policy)
```

I know my IAM user and policies are correct, because if I change the "sandbox" credentials to the "default" credentials, it works perfectly.

Any suggestions on how to get this working??   Seems like telling the AWSSDK to look at a specific profile should be easy, but apparently it's not.

Thanks.